# In Python how do you reverse this call: long("1234", 16)?

Tags: python, binary, hex

I'd like to be able to do the reverse of:

`foo = long(binarystring.encode('hex'), 16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use string formatting and then decode the result.

```
>>> binarystring = "asddfsdf"
>>> tmp = long(binarystring.encode('hex'),16)
>>> ( "%x" % tmp ).decode('hex')
'asddfsdf'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [7]: long("1234", 16)
Out[7]: 4660L

In [8]: hex(4660L)[2:-1]
Out[8]: '1234'
```

The `[2:-1]` discards the leading `0x` and the trailing `L`.

Comment: Cheers for the answer, I preferred the answer that didn't need messing with string too much.

Answer (score 0):

use binascii.hexlify() - that should do it